# React Native How to change the color of the top portion of the iphone where the wifi and time is displayed

Tags: react-native

I am unable to change the color of the top portion of the iPhone where the wifi and time is displayed, and I was wondering if anyone knew how to do it. It is not the portion where the back button is, but instead in the spot where the time is shown with the wifi and data sign. Any help would be largely appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: check StatusBar in React Native - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar#barstyle

Comment: How would I implement this in a screen?

Comment: The status bar background color property seems to work for Android only. Is there any way to make it work for IOS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since iOS doesn't have a `backgroundColor` prop of the status bar, I found a different approach.

Normally the height of the status bar

- `44` for safe iPhoneX
- `30` for unsafe iPhoneX
- `20` for other iOS devices
- `StatusBar.currentHeight` for Android

Check below sample code & modify it according to your requirements. This works both iOS & Android devices.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, StatusBar, Platform } from "react-native";

const STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === "ios" ? 20 : StatusBar.currentHeight;
const HEADER_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === "ios" ? 44 : 56;

export default class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ height: STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT, backgroundColor: "#5E8D48" }}>
          <StatusBar
            translucent
            backgroundColor="#5E8D48"
            barStyle="light-content"
          />
        </View>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#79B45D", height: HEADER_HEIGHT }} />
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#33373B" }}>
          {/* Display your content */}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this will helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: This piece of code is the only code on the internet that works for me. I appreciate your help and the effort that you put into answering this question for me. Thank you!

Comment: This just puts the two greens in bars above my app, but the iPhone X top bar is still there, and now it's completely blank. (no time or signal)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the StatusBar component to take control of animating, style, network activity, etc. on every view in Android and iOS.
For example, set the color of the status bar text via barStyle prop with the value of 'light-content' or 'dark-content'. The default value is 'default'

Here's an example:

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StatusBar } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="aqua" barStyle="light-content" />
      <Text>Test status bar screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In iOS, this area behind the status bar is actually an extension of your app's canvas so there are a couple of ways you can emulate a status bar color.

Firstly, you can utilise [SafeAreaView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/safeareaview). On iOS, this view will embed it's children in a view that excludes unusable areas of the device (status bar, home bar on iPhone X series, curves in the display). If you embed your screen inside this component and give it a background color, that color will apply to both the status bar and home bar: https://snack.expo.io/@jrdndncn/excited-marshmallows

Alternatively, you could just create a full width, colored view at the top of your app view with the height of the devices status bar. You can either implement this yourself by detecting the device or using a small library such as [react-native-status-bar-height](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-status-bar-height). Just bear in mind that unless you've explicitly asked for a transparent status bar on Android, your app canvas will start below it's status bar so you'll need to assume the height of your custom view is always 0 on Android.

Comment: The `SafeAreaView` solution sounds great but isn't working for me :/

Answer (score 1):

u can use SafeAreaView to get this effect

```
const component = () => {
 return (
      <>
      <SafeAreaView style={{backgroundColor: 'color'}} />
      <SafeAreaView forceInset={{top: 'always'}} style={{flex: 1}}>
      </SafeAreaView>
      </>
    );
}
```

if u want to change android statusbar color then u have to use Statusbar from 'react-native' and set backgroundColor